# Rolling a Fair dice 6 times

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If I roll a fair dice 6 times, which event is more likely

A) 1,1,1,1,1,1
B) 3,2,2,5,1,6

The probability of (A) occuring is [1/6]^6 = 2.14E-05.  I'm not too sure how to calculate (B)'s probability but I suspect it's more likely.. or maybe the likeliness of either A or B occuring cannot be determined ?

Thanks

Comment: Since it's a fair die, every face has equal probability of appearing upon rolling. So, both the events are equally likely.

Comment: Does the order of numbers in (B) matter?

Comment: There are $6^6$ sequences possible and occurrence of any sequence is equally likely

Answer (score 0):

Since the assumption is that the dice is "fair", then every face of the dice has an equiprobable chance of appearing. Thus

$$P(1) = P(2) = P(3) = P(4) = P(5) = P(6) = \frac{1}{6}$$

This means that any 6 successive combination of faces have $({\frac{1}{6}})^6 = \frac{1}{46656}$ chances of happening.